# showAsAction="always" does not work when in two-pane mode

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-menu

I tried setting the menu items in my app as actions with app:showAsAction="always". This works on a phone and also on the tablet when I use the same layout.

But when I use a two-pane layout, the items don't show up in the action bar but in the overflow menu even though there is plenty of room.

Here is the menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_maps"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_place"
        android:orderInCategory="20"
        android:title="@string/maps_menu_item"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_event"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_event"
        android:orderInCategory="30"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_event"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share_gig"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_share"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Here is the two-pane layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
     >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/gig_list"
        android:name="de.nobodyknows.app.GigListFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/gig_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my code I use the callback method to replace the FrameLayout with a detail fragment:

```
/**
 * Callback method from {@link GigListFragment.Callbacks} indicating that
 * the item with the given ID was selected.
 */
@Override
public void onItemSelected(Long id) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putLong(GigDetailFragment.GIG_ID, id);
        GigDetailFragment fragment = new GigDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.gig_detail_container, fragment).commit();

    } else {
        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, GigDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(GigDetailFragment.GIG_ID, id);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}
```

The detail Fragment inflates the options menu that was shown above:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
    }
```

Now these menu items show up fine in the phone layout when a new acticity is started. But when the fragment replaces the FrameLayout in the first activity, the menu items just show up in the overflow menu. I can't figure out why that happens, though. Has it something to do with the support library? Or is it something special about how fragments work?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution.

My Activity did not extend the[`ActionBarActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)and therefore was not correctly set up to work with `MenuItemCompat`.
The reason why it still worked on the phone was because that was in a different Activity that correctly extended `ActionBarActivity`.

To correct this I just replaced the superclass of the Activity that acts as the two-pane Activity to be `ActionBarActivity`.